# Insert random string into field with MySQL UNI key

Tags: mysql, random, indexing, unique, populate

The task is to fill the table with N rows of random unique data.

I have the next MySQL table structure:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(20)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Username field has string type but if the script will insert numbers its OK.

Theres is dirty solution with `INSERT IGNORE`, that can make 1000 random rows with endless cycle.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (id,username) VALUES ('', 1 + ceil(rand() * 1000));
```

Also, I can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY` structure, but this 2 solutions are not OK.

I want to make the query, that generate unique username which will be unique and will be inserted from the first time.

So, I tell the script to add 1m of rows and it will insert 1m of unique data without any infelicities.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UUID() which will give you a random string which would fit in your field, guaranteed to be unique with slim chance of collisions.